# How to find web element in nested xml by using xpath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to click an element on menu in an e-commerce web-site by using xpath but i'm not able to find it.

I directly tried to reach it by the following one but it didn't work.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"w_1561138892240_cbx\"]")).click();
```

Then i tried to reach it by taking nested xml into consideration also but couldn't do it again.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@name='Brand']//div[@id='w1-w1-w0-w0-multiselect[8]']//input[@id='w_1561136068937_cbx']")).click();
```

How can i fix this issue ?

[nested xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKB10.png)
[nested xml 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKzyG.png)

Comment: Please post the relevant html.

Comment: Please avoid proving screenshot.It would be great if you post html in text format.

Comment: i don't know how to export and post the xml displayed in inspector of firefox

Comment: Have you tried the answer code I have posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the xpath that you can use.

```
//li[contains(@class,'__list--aspect')]//input[@aria-label='Apple']
```

If you want to strictly use id then use below (not suggested)

```
 //li[contains(@class,'__list--aspect')]//input[@id='w_1561151835676_cbx']
```

**Scrrenshot**
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your first suggest worked. It's really weird not working when being used id value.

Comment: I would not suggest using the id, because it might be dynamic and your xpath will break in that case. So, it's always suggestible to go with static attribute & values. `FYI:-`  And also observed the `\"` which masked the `"`, this is not required unless you have the single/double quotes as part of the attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

To handle dynamic element use `WebdriverWait` Try the following xpath to click on the element.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[@name='Brand']//input[@type='checkbox' and @aria-label='Apple']"))).click();
```